# Excel list all sheet in system object variable to pass to for each loop container in SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis

[image]I am trying to pass each "Sheet Name" in XLSX file to   variable in SSIS  , so that I can process each sheet name . I want to get one sheet name  at a time store it in variable run Data flow task , then get second sheet name store it variable run data flow and so on . I am process this script in "Get Excel sheet" 
Below is my code , please help me . Thanks in advance

```
string connectionString = null;
OleDbConnection excelConnection = null;
DataTable tablesInFile = null;
int tableCount = 0;
DataRow tableInFile = null;
string currentTable = null;
int tableIndex = 0;
string[] excelTables = null;



connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + "D:\\ETL\\Sample.xlsx;" + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES\";";

excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

excelConnection.Open();
tablesInFile = excelConnection.GetSchema("Tables");

tableCount = tablesInFile.Rows.Count;
excelTables = new string[tableCount];

foreach (DataRow tableInFile_loopVariable in tablesInFile.Rows)
{
tableInFile = tableInFile_loopVariable;
currentTable = tableInFile["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
excelTables[tableIndex] = currentTable;
tableIndex += 1;
}
            Dts.Variables["User::Test"].Value = excelTables[0];

            foreach (String str in excelTables)
            {


                MessageBox.Show(str);
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

        }
```